# Authenticate before serving up directory in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, express, routes

I am having trouble trying to authenticate users before they view an express directory file tree.  I can authenticate on all other pages but not on "/dat/:file(*)" even when I pass the authentication route before downloading the file.
  So when a user goes to '/', express will redirect them if they are not logged in.  But, if a user goes to '/dat', express will not authenticate and will allow them to browse the file tree. I'm using express@3.4.8 and any help would be great. Thanks!

```
app.configure( function() {
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');

    app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.use('/dat', express.directory(__dirname + '/public/dat', {hidden: true, icons: true}));

    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.cookieParser('secret'));
    app.use(express.session({
        secret: 'secret',
        maxAge: 3600000
    }));
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    app.use(app.router);
});

app.get('/', ensure_authenticated, routes.index);
app.get('/dat/:file(*)', ensure_authenticated, function(req, res, next) {
    var path = __dirname + '/' + req.params.file;
    res.download(path);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The order of your middleware matters.

```
app.use('/dat', express.directory(__dirname + '/public/dat', {hidden: true, icons: true}));
```

Is before:

```
app.get('/dat/:file(*)', ensure_authenticated, function(req, res, next) {
    var path = __dirname + '/' + req.params.file;
    res.download(path);
});
```

As a result, the first middleware is handling the request.

Moving the first route after `app.use(app.router))` should fix this.

You'll also want to add `ensure_authenticate` to the route for `express.directory` if you want the user to be authenticated to see the directory listing as well.

```
app.use('/dat', ensure_authenticate, express.directory ...
```

Comment: Thanks Jordonias this makes sense and asks to authenticate before it routes you to "/dat".  However, now when I authenticate and then go to '/dat' it tries to serve up a static html file instead of the file tree...